# pastured chicken?

Tags: word-usage

In China, we have chickens called *Tuji* that are not kept in cages, instead, they are kept in large enclosed fences and are always allowed to wander outside their enclosure.They are fed with corns, rice instead of chicken feed.

A) Can I call this kind of chicken pastured chickens? I think pastured chickens in the UK are raised in a similar way. B)Should I call it *Tuji* with some explanations after it.

Which sounds more reasonable to native speakers? Thank you.[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the term "pastured chicken"  However it seems to mean that the hens are encouraged to feed on insects etc that they find in the field.  How does 土鸡 differ from 散养鸡

Comment: I quite like the term "pastured chickens". I bet you can buy them in Waitrose (a posh supermarket in UK).

Comment: 土鸡（Tuji） means these chickens are raised by farmers on a small scale, no more than 30. The farmers always allow them to wander outside their enclosure. They are fed with corns and rice and they can scratch for insects themselves. 散养鸡（sanyangji) refers to chickens raised on a large scale, at least one hundred. The farmers may rent a part of a mountain to raise 散养鸡. They might be fed with chicken feed instead of corns or rice. For Chinese people, we favor 土鸡 over 散养鸡. However, because 土鸡 are way fewer than 散养鸡 in the market, so we often eat 散养鸡。

Comment: In addition, 土鸡（Tuji） cost much more than 散养鸡（Sanyangji).

Answer (score 4):

In the UK and America, people are familiar with the term 'free-range', especially for poultry (chicken, turkey, duck, etc) and also eggs. The term does not automatically imply that a hen was fed on corn, so you could talk of meat or eggs from 'free-range corn-fed chickens'.

> free-range
>
> adjective
>
> relating to or produced by farm animals that are allowed to move around
> outside and are not kept in cages:
>
> *free-range eggs/chickens*

[Free-range (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-range)

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we call these "[free-range](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-range?q=Free-range)" chickens.